# Is there an application to write down URLs?

Tags: url, google-chrome-extensions, android

Is there an application to write down URLs in a single-unified-online accessible place ?

I often find interesting articles but I often forget to write down the URLs.

Is there an application which allow you to write down the URLs and keep track of the history of what you have written down (ideally with notes you could type for each URL) which would sync over multiple instances of Chrome/Android ?

Ideally I need a system which could export files as my work blocks most of the solutions and which could merge the URLs into a system where it could be shared between:

- work
- home desktop
- android / iOS devices

Comment: [Evernote](http://evernote.com/)?

Comment: Or any other online bookmarking service?

Comment: You can sync your plain old browser bookmarks. No extension needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways of *writing down* your URL's. I personally am a sucker for Delicious even though the service has been facing some issue. The only reason I am stuck with them is because I have over 4000 bookmarks and have a few stacks which I like.

Usually, you can use a combination of one or more services:

1. Look at [Faveous](http://www.faveous.com/). Its a little buggy with twitter and facebook integration, but I like the concept.
2. [Evernote](http://evernote.com) - This syncs across computers and mobile devices and helps you create notebooks and stacks and share them.
3. [Delicious](http://delicious.com) - Has browser plugins to easily bookmark pages and can be synced easily between mobile devices and browsers.
4. [Licorize](http://licorize.com/) - Like Delicious, pages can be bookmarked using a bookmarklet, a Chrome or Firefox extension, or via the website.
5. [Pinboard](http://pinboard.in/) is a “back to basics” bookmarking service. It’s similar to Delicious, but has a stripped-back user interface and is designed to be extremely fast to use; it’s good for users who have grown frustrated with Delicious’ sluggishness; its paid though
6. [Diigo](http://www.diigo.com/) goes beyond simple social bookmarking by providing a wealth of features, including collaboration and web page commenting tools;
7. [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/) - A very basic bookmarking service that lets you tag bookmarks, but personally I don't like it. Its very basic

Comment: I will let the question open for a few hours but I think your solution is very complete.

Comment: Fine list! I would also add [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/) and [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/).